# firefox password autocomplete not working

Tags: html, firefox, autocomplete, passwords

I have a webapp with a simple login page

```
    <form id="logonForm" method="post" action="j_security_check">
      <fieldset id="logon">
        <input id="ipt_j_username" type="text" name="j_username" value="<bean:write name="user" />" title="some title" />
        <input id="ipt_j_password" type="password" name="j_password" value="<bean:write name="password" />" title=" some title" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Once I entered the login/pwd, FF asked me to save it, which I accepted (in the list of saved passwords in FF there is a pair user/pwd for my url). So now the username/pwd fields are automatically pre-filled each time I visit my login page. So far it's ok.

I did some development on my login form and I changed the id attributes for the user and pwd inputs.

```
<form id="logonForm" method="post" action="j_security_check">
  <input id="IDUser" type="text"  name="j_username" value="<bean:write name="user" />" title="some title" />
  <input id="passUser" type="password"  name="j_password" value="<bean:write name="password" />" title="some title" />
</form>
```

After this change, FF stopped autocompleting my inputs. FF is not asking me to save the user/pwd since the used combination was already saved before. Of course, if I manually delete the saved user/pwd for my url then FF will ask me to save it and everything will work fine.

Can someone explain to me how FF is mapping input fields with saved user/pwd values? With my example, it looks like FF is using the id attributes for this. Somewhere I saw that it's enough to have input with type="password" for FF but in my case this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a "feature" in the form filling code. Try this:

Remove the entry for this page from your "saved passwords" list. When you visit the page again, Firefox should ask once more to save the password.

Background: There are sites which change the name of the password field for each request to make sure that the browser can't save it. My guess is that FF notices this and stops asking to avoid nagging you with a useless "save password" dialog for sites where it doesn't work.

Comment: hello and thank you for the reply. First of all, I didnt change name attribute in the inputs so I dont understand why FF is not autocompleting my inputs. Yes, If I delete saved passwords in FF options everything will work, but I cannot to ask all clients to do that..

Comment: If deleting the password entry in the privacy settings works, then the next question is which information is used by FF to determine that this field is the same as before. Maybe ask on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/